# Swift generic function call underlying method based on generic type

Tags: swift, generics, metatype

I am writing an interface to Someone Else's Code (SEC), and I have a long list of functions more or less like this:

```
public func readString(_ row: Row, columnName: String) -> String? {
    return SEC.getString(row, columnName)
}

public func readInt(_ row: Row, columnName: String) -> Int? {
    return SEC.getInt(row, columnName)
}
```

And so on.

What I would like to do is have a single function:

```
public func read<T>(_ row: Row, columnName: String) -> T? {
    // call correct SEC.get* method
}
```

I tried a simple switch statement on `T` and on `T.Type`, but no dice. I also tried a modified version of the above:

```
public func read<T: ReadableType>(_ row: Row, columnName: String) -> T? {
    let getter = T.getterMethod
    return getter(row, columnName)
}
```

Where I could create an `enum` of the metatypes that had `SEC.get*` functions, and extend it to return the proper getter method. This to me seemed ideal. Alas:

```
public enum ReadableTypes {
    case String.Type       // nope
    case Int.self          // also nope
}
```

I'm not sure what else to try; it's not the end of the world if I simply have a dozen read* methods, but the code that calls this method could be so dang tight if I could make it generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can individually test to see what type the generic placeholder represents like this:

```
if T.self is Int.Type //...
```

The same sort of test can be done in a `switch..case` statement.

Assuming `SEC` is of type `SECType` what I'd do is extend `SECType` to have a generic `get` method that keys on the return type:

```
extension SECType {
  public func get<T>(_ row: Row, _ columnName: String) -> T? {
    // switch on the generic type
    switch T.self {
    // As much as I dislike force-unwrapping an Optional
    // this is about as safe as it gets.
    case is Int.Type   : return getInt   (row, columnName) as! T?
    case is String.Type: return getString(row, columnName) as! T?
    //...
    default: return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can write your own `read` function like:

```
public func read<T>(_ row: Row, columnName: String) -> T? {
  return SEC.get(row, columnName)
}
```

Of course you can skip doing the `extension` and just do a generic function with a `switch`. However, it's harmless to add the method to the type and it makes sense for the type to have a generic method like this.

Comment: Very cool, but note that the answer to the OP's actual question is simply the phrase `if T.self is Int.Type`. That's the missing piece of his puzzle — the syntax for asking about the type to which the generic placeholder has been resolved.

Comment: @matt True, it can be boiled down to that phrase. I did it with a `switch` to show how to cover more than one test at a time since it was mentioned that there was a "long list of functions" like those. I'll add that to the answer to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Absolutely - I'm just responding to his "I tried a simple switch statement on T and on T.Type". He didn't try it on T.self, and he wouldn't have thought to compare with Int.Type (Int alone won't work, as it is not a metatype).

Comment: Thanks! It would have taken me a long time to reach that syntax they way I was going.